# How to attach words/phrases from column A to sentences in column B?

Tags: python, regex

I have a spreadsheed with two columns and a couple of thousands rows. Column A contains words or phrases whereas column B contains example(s) of sentences with those words/phrases from column A. Some of the cells in column B contain more than one sentence (separated by "< li>" tags).

It looks like this (forgive me but I don't know how to produce a html table, so column A is here represented in bold):

---

***active participation/involvement**Active participation in community life is important in small towns and villages. The school encourages the active involvement of parents.

**made...abundantly clear**She’d made her feelings towards him abundantly clear.*

---

I need to attach words/phrases from column A to each and every item (sentence) in column B. Ideally I would like to have each example sentence in a separate row (in column B) with a relevant word/phrase in column A like this:

---

***active participation/involvement**  Active participation in community life is important in small towns...
**active participation/involvement**The school encourages the active involvement of parents.*

---

I'm not a programmer and know just the very basics of python. Do I need to use regular expressions? Will appreciate any help. thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem a bit? Is the two column arrangement in the data already and you want to clean it up by making sure each row has only one phrase and one example?

Comment: Yes precisely, I need to cleen it up. What I have looks like this: "<b>address a meeting/conference etc</b> <li>He addressed an audience of 10,000 supporters.</li> <div><I></I></div>
<b>address a problem/question/issue etc</b> <li>Our products address the needs of real users.</li> <div><I></I></div>
<b>stamped, self-addressed envelope</b> <li>Send a stamped, self-addressed envelope.</li> <div><I>with your address on it so it can be sent back to you</I></div>
<b>sb’s home/private address</b> <li>What’s your home address?</li> <div><I></I></div>
"

Comment: Is it an HTML file? Try [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the solution is adding a line with column A content in between lines in column B, I would recommend just exporting the spreadsheet to CSV and then using python CSV libraries to read column A and B in a line. Then you can replace -

```
with open('spreadsheet.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for row in csv_reader:
        colum_a = row[0]
        colum_b = row[1]
        print "%s,%s%s" % (colum_a,colum_b.replace("</li><li>","</li><li>%s</li><li>" % str(colum_a)),"\n\r")
```